# If $S$ is countable then $S_0 \subset S$ is countable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Define "countable" in the following way:

$S$ is said to be countable if $S$ is finite OR $|\mathbb{N}| = |S|$.

So my textbook proves the theorem by considering two cases.

**Case 1**: $S$ is finite. Then any subset $S_0$ is clearly finite as well. So by definition $S_0$ is countable.

**Case 2:** $S$ is infinite. Then the proof proceeds...

I don't understand why we are considering these two cases, i.e. why do we consider $S$ is finite or infinite...?

We have the hypothesis that $S$ is countable MEANING $S$ is finite or $|\mathbb{N}| = |S|$. In particular we have that $S$ is finite why are we considering these two seeming weird cases?

**Like aren't we trying to show $S_0$ is countable i.e. aren't we trying to show that $S_0$ is finite or its cardinality is the same as the natural numbers?**

**My proof**: $S$ is countable so $S$ is finite OR $|\mathbb{N}|=|S|$.

Case 1: $S$ is finite

Case 2: $|\mathbb{N}|=|S|$

To be more specific with my question: why aren't we considering these two above cases? Logically the countable definition has an "OR" meaning we must consider finite or the other case naturally.

Comment: Your proof doesn't even mention $S_0$, so how can it possibly be proving anything about $S_0$?

Comment: By definition of countability, if $S_0$ is not finite, then you need to construct a bijection $\mathbb{N} \to S_0$. Since this is impossible if $S_0$ is finite (because $\mathbb{N}$ is infinite),  we must distinguish the cases.

Comment: We are indeed trying to show that $S_0$ is either finite our countably infinite. Why your textbook separates into two cases depends on the approach the author is taking. Depending on what results you already have, you might not need that assumption

Comment: The case "$S$ is infinite" refers to the case $|S| =|\mathbb{N}|$.

Comment: But that's how my textbook defined $S$ being countable though..

Comment: @javacoder Your textbook defines countable as finite OR countable infinite. So countable does not imply finite but finite implies countable

Comment: Part of your criticism is valid: perhaps the author meant "infinite" as in "countably infinite". Indeed, the statement wouldn't hold if $S$ is any infinite set (for example $S=\Bbb R$ and $S_0=\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$). But "finite or countable" doesn't imply "finite" (that would be the case if it was "and" instead of "or").

Comment: The textbook said $S$ is countable means $S$ is finite **or** $|S|=|\mathbb{N}|$. The second case here implies that $S$ is not finite. (If A is true **or** B is true, it does not necessarily mean that A is true.)

Comment: The way this proof often goes is as follows: if $S_0$ is finite then it is countable and we are done. Otherwise, we construct a bijection between $S_0$ and $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Why is it not more logical to consider case 1 being $S$ finite and case 2 being $|\mathbb{N}|=|S|$?

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH I got it!! The case 2 i said is really the same as the author!!!!! Yayyyyyyyyyy thank you so much!!!! :D